# Japanese word for Operation, in the sense of a project or task - slang

Tags: translation, slang

What would be the Japanese equivalent of the word **operation**, in the sense of a project or task?

Some examples would be:

- Operation Infiltrate-the-Castle
- Operation Human Shield (from South Park)
- Operation *random cool name*

In English this usage obviously comes from a military background, but what is the corresponding Japanese term? **And more importantly, would you use this in the same tongue-in-cheek manner as in English, to glorify some task or project and make it sound exciting?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easiest to give a familiar example

> Operation Desert Shield｜砂漠の盾作戦

ie place the name of the operation in front of 作戦　（さくせん）

I think you could get away with using katakana words for foreign activties.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know whether this is also used out of the military context in Japanese?

Comment: You can use 大作戦{だいさくせん} as well - as in 京都大作戦 (a music festival) or プロポーズ大作戦 (name of a drama). Further on the slangy side, nicodic lists "パンツ大作戦" (not as dirty as it sounds!)

Comment: If you browse Space Alc you will see that most of the time it is used for military campaigns but not exclusively.